# Python reverse iteration to split a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to split my words from my punctuation-
I'm thinking about having the function look at each word and determining if there is a punctuation mark in it by starting at [-1], index of -1, and then splitting the word from the punctuation as soon as it hits a letter and not a punctuation mark...

```
sent=['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'best', 'movie!','Do','you', 'want', 'to', 'see', 'it', 'again!?!']
import string
def revF(List):
    for word in List:
        for ch in word[::-1]:
            if ch is string.punctuation:
                 #go to next character and check if it's punctuation
                newList= #then split the word between the last letter and first puctuation mark
    return newList
```

Comment: For your given example, what do you want the answer to be?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to remove punctuation from a string. Python provides much better ways of doing this -

```
>>> import string
>>> line
'I went to the best movie! Do you want to see it again!?!'
>>> line.translate(None, string.punctuation)
'I went to the best movie Do you want to see it again'
```

Comment: Can I somehow add the punctuation back in?

Comment: @user2553807 do you want remove punctuation or add punctuation. Be clear in what you need.

Comment: There's no way to tell where, how much, or what kind of punctuation used to be in "asdf". It could've been "asdf.", "!asdf", or "asdf@#$%". It's like trying to tell what was on a part of a piece of paper you tore off and threw away. You'll have to keep the original string, or record what you removed.

Comment: so to understand more for your given example, what will the answer to be?

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I gather that you want to split your string on a space. You can do this quite simply like this:

```
my_str = "I went to the best movie! Do you want to see it again!?!"
sent   = my_str.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp containing the punctuation you want to split on:

```
re.split('re.split(r"[!?.]", text)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"[!?.]", 'bra det. där du! som du gjorde?')
['bra det', ' d\xc3\xa4r du', ' som du gjorde', '']
```